# Regex : How to Extract HTML Heading Tags

Tags: php, regex

Extract all heading tags (h1, h2, h3, ...) and it's content. For example :

```
<h1 id="title">This is the title</h1>
<h2 id="subtitle">This is the subtitle</h2>
<p>And this is the paragraph</p>
```

Will be extracted as :

`<h1 id="title">This is the title</h1>` and `<h2 id="subtitle">This is the subtitle</h2>`

I'm using PHP and using regex as the title say.

Comment: What language are you using? A parser would be rather easy for this task.

Comment: Regexp should not be appropriate to achieve what you want, what you wanna use is `innerHtml`

Comment: Please provide more information

Comment: I'm using PHP and regex

Comment: So, and what regex are you using? If that's what you prefer, you probably already tried something? What issues did you run into?

Comment: @mario..I want to preg_replace() all the heading tags. And still trying to find the right pattern for that.

Comment: Anything like [this](https://regex101.com/r/sD4bF3/1)?  If not, provide additional requirements.

Comment: @PM 77-1.. Yes, thank you very much.. I was trying with /^<h(.*)>$/ but still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to use the right [**tool**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for the task.

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadHTML('
    <h1 id="title">This is the title</h1>
    <h2 id="subtitle">This is the subtitle</h2>
    <p>And this is the paragraph</p>
    <p>another tag</p>
');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);  
$heads = $xpath->query('//h1|//h2|//h3|//h4|//h5|//h6');

foreach ($heads as $tag) {
   echo $doc->saveHTML($tag), "\n";
}
```

Output

```
<h1 id="title">This is the title</h1>
<h2 id="subtitle">This is the subtitle</h2>
```